# Style frozen columns in Wijmo FlexGrid

Tags: css, reactjs, wijmo, wijmo5

I have columns and rows on my React application, I use Wijmo Flexgrid, and I freeze some columns. I want to have wider border at the end of the frozen columns, but it's as small as other column borders.
Photo from Wijmo example:
[image]

https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/demos/Grid/Columns/Freezing/react

Photo from Google Sheet example:

[image]

I want to have wider borders at the end of frozen columns, how can I achieve this?